# How to specify the initial playback time when playing video on UIWebview?

Tags: ios, webview

I am making use of webview's `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` property for playing videos.

Is there any way to set the initial playback time?

Comment: Are you able to modify the content that is being displayed?

Comment: I am able to play different video urls and able to seek to a particular time.Now I am seeking the video to a particular value on playback starts .

Comment: Are you able to modify the source code of the page the video is embedded in though?

Comment: I am using Daily motion sdks to play videos in web view. They have provided method for seek,pause etc

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use

```
[UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:];
```

And pass in a piece of JS that calls the seek function on the player.